# menucommandservice with basicdesignerloader

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm working on a project where the user can add/edit controls to a surface as described here [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163634.aspx)

Everything works fine as for the editing and saving.
I'm using a BasicDesignerLoader instead of the CodeDomDesignerLoader since we do not want to generate vb or c# code but rather load and save as XML.

For some reason, the MenuCommandService does not work with a BasicDesignerLoader.  It'll work fine though if I change to a CodeDomDesignerLoader but then the XML part gets quirky.

Has someone found a way to be able to use a MenuCommandService while under a BasicDesignerLoader?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note : The Delete command works but not cut/copy/paste

Comment: Did you ever figure out why Delete worked and Copy and Paste did not? I have the same issue and finding information about this these days is difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on similar project and I start from a Microsoft sample.
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;813808
This serialize in XML but it does not use BasicDesignerLoader (it implements a DesignerLoader inheriting from DesignerLoader).
After some fixes on ContextMenu it works fine (main bug is about chaching last context menu).

Actually, in the implementation of the DesignerLoader there are several service registrations.
It could be that in BasicDesignerLoader something's missing...